# Is the isset() function below placed correctly?

Tags: php

I have this code below and the problem is that it is not uploading the file and the call back javascript function at the bottom isn't displaying the result. Now before I entered in the if isset ($_POST[fileImage'])... code, and the `$_SESSION['fileImage']['name'] = $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];`, then the files uploaded perfectly.But with those 2 pieces of code, it has stopped the uploading from happening.

So I believe the problem is that the code above I have used have been placed in the wrong places. How can the code below be placed correctly in the right places for the uploading to start working again?

Below is the code which is suppose to upload the files but fails:

```
  <?php

    $result = 0;

       if (isset($_POST['fileImage']) && ((($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/tif"))){

    if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {  

        $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
        $ext = array_pop($parts);
        $base = implode(".",$parts);
        $n = 2;

        while( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
        $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], 
        "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
        $result = 1;

    }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
          "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
          $result = 1;

          }

          ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);
</script>   

          <?php

    }

      $_SESSION['fileImage']['name'] = $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

    ?>
```

Comment: Just a reminder: $_FILES["file"]["type"] is not safe to determine the file type. This information is provided by the browser. You should deploy additional checks to make sure it's an image or to protect the folder where the file is placed against execution.

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing your form, but my guess is that `$_POST['fileImage']` is not set.  I'd just check `isset($_FILES['fileimage'])` and that `$_FILES['fileimage']['error'] == 0`.  If you have a file input field `fileimage`, then `$_POST['fileimage']` does not get populated.  Only `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using using both `$_FILES["fileImage"]` and `$_POST['fileImage']` and am not sure  that is correct .

The way you have also written does not make it clean enough to easily identify errors .. you can use this

Try

```
<?php

$result = 0;
$errors = array ();
$dirImage = "ImageFiles/";

$allowedTypes = array (
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/gif",
        "image/pjpeg",
        "image/jpg",
        "image/png",
        "image/tif" 
);

if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['size'];
    $fileTemp = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['type'];

    $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );

    if (empty ( $fileName ))
        continue;

    if (! in_array ( $fileType, $allowedTypes )) {
        $errors [] = "File Type is not accepted";

    }

    if(!is_writable($dirImage ))
    {
        $errors [] = "File Destination not writeable";
    }


    $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
    $filePrifix = basename ( $fileName, "." . $fileExt );
    $i = 0;
    while ( file_exists ( $fileDst ) ) {
        $i ++;
        $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePrifix . "_" . $i . "." . $fileExt;

    }
    // Move the file

    if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
        if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
            $result = 1;
        }
    }

}

$_SESSION ['fileImage'] ['name'] = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];
?>
```

Please note that the errors are stored in `$errors` variable and what i advice is for you ro convert it to `json` can call it via your JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a function to handle the upload:

```
function handleImageUpload()
{
    // was a file uploaded?
    if (!isset($_FILES['fileImage'])) {
        return;
    }
    if (!isImage($_FILES['fileImage'])) {
        // consider throwing an exception here
        return;
    }
    $savepath = getFileSavePath($_FILES['fileImage'], 'ImageFiles/')
    // handle upload
    // ...
}

function isImage($imagepath)
{
    // return boolean 
}

function getFileSavePath($uploadpath, $destinationdirectory)
{
    // return path to save upload without overwriting any existing file
}
```

Consider using `pathinfo()` to get information about the file. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php